# Getting song meta data

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to get the metadata from an absolute URL to a song, such as `http://www.<url>.com/<file>.mp3`

How do I go about doing this. I'm a little new to the C# api's so I'm a little lost in terms of what classes to use.

I found this block of code from searching around:

```
StorageFile newFile = //file
var prop =await  newFile.Properties.GetMusicPropertiesAsync();
string album = prop.Album;
```

and I was wondering what goes in the //file field? What class is of type `StorageFile` that will take in a URI?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can download the mp3 file to local using this:

```
WebClient Client = new WebClient ();
Client.DownloadFile("http://myserver.com/indie/band1.mp3", "band1.mp3");
```

Then, use TagLibSharp https://github.com/mono/taglib-sharp

```
//Local reference to the file
TagLib.File file = TagLib.File.Create("band1.mp3");

//Get the file metadata
Console.WriteLine("Tags on disk: " + file.TagTypesOnDisk);
Console.WriteLine("Tags in object: " + file.TagTypes);

Write ("Grouping", file.Tag.Grouping);
Write ("Title", file.Tag.Title);
Write ("Album Artists", file.Tag.AlbumArtists);
Write ("Performers", file.Tag.Performers);
Write ("Composers", file.Tag.Composers);
Write ("Conductor", file.Tag.Conductor);
Write ("Album", file.Tag.Album);
Write ("Genres", file.Tag.Genres);
Write ("BPM", file.Tag.BeatsPerMinute);
Write ("Year", file.Tag.Year);
Write ("Track", file.Tag.Track);
Write ("TrackCount", file.Tag.TrackCount);
Write ("Disc", file.Tag.Disc);
Write ("DiscCount", file.Tag.DiscCount);
```